# how to add javascript language to JSR223 Sampler language selection option in Jmeter application

Tags: javascript, database, jmeter, jsr223

I have created a code in javascript language to display data in the database, I use the Jmeter application to see the performance of the database and use JSR223 Sampler.

but when I choose the language option there is no option for javascript language.

for that please give me instructions to add javascript language options in JSR223 Sampler Jmeter application

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript language support [has been removed in OpenJDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so the options are in:

1. Downgrade your JVM to the previous version. The lowest version you can run JMeter with is [Java 8](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk8/).
2. Use alternative JVM like [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/)
3. Switch to another language. Using JavaScript is some form of a performance anti-pattern, it's [recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223). More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)